# Apply CSS rules based on other rule - RTL specific style

Tags: css, sass, right-to-left

## Presentation

I'm trying to build a web site available in multiple cultures, with different reading direction.

To do so, I simply add the `dir="rtl"` attribute on my root HTML element.

My issue is that I have some CSS rules that are specific to one direction or the other (margins or paddings, most of the times).

## Unsuccessful try with attribute selector

I though that I could simply use [the attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) but the `dir` attribute is only set on the root element, so this wouldn't work :

```
selector {
  &[dir="ltr"] {
    // LTR specific
  }

  &[dir="rtl"] {
    // RTL specific
  }
}
```

For instance, on this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y381ajap/2/), the title should have a margin of 5px on the right if the application is in `rtl` or on the left if it's in standard `ltr`.

## Other idea

I've noticed that the `direction` is rightfully set at `rtl`, is there a way to use that rule within a `CSS` or `Sass` selector ?

## Edit and precisions

It seems that I've forgotten an important point. I'm building the web site using Vue.js, the `dir` attribute is bind in the main component (`App`) and the RTL/LTR specific CSS rules can be in the same component or in other self-contained component.

Answer (score 3):

Following your css code you could do this with SASS `at-root` directive [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMqppN). So this:

```
#app {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;

  h1 {
    @at-root {
      [dir="rtl"]#{&} {color: green}
    }

    @at-root {
      [dir="ltr"]#{&} {color: red}
    }
  }
}
```

It will compile to this css.

```
#app {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
[dir="rtl"]#app h1 {
  color: green;
}
[dir="ltr"]#app h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it works for the css I've provided but as I've pointed out in the edit, I'm building a Vue.js application with several self-contained components. Should I add the `#app` selector in each and every components ?

Comment: No, ids must be unique so you can have only one `#app` on page, I just realized i made that mistake in my example, you could use classes in that case https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMqppN. And `@at-root` will refer to top level selector of your nested selectors in your sass code so it will work in this scenario you provided but i am not sure for others.

Comment: I only have one id on the main component, that is only injected once. But as you said, it will only work if I nest all of my style in a `#app` selector.
I'm upvoting your answer since it's valid solution for the basic issue but I cannot validate it.

Comment: Sure thing, I hope that someone will come up with better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could style everything LTR, and only adjust some elements styling for RTL. Might this work for you?

```
[dir="rtl"] {
    &selector {
        // RTL specific
    }

    &selectorN {
        // RTL specific
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution would work but, as I've explained in my edit, I'm building a large scale application using Vue.js (with self-contained components).

Answer (score 1):

Use below scss to get expected output

```
#app {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;

  &[dir="ltr"] h1{
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  &[dir="rtl"] h1 {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are going a little in the wrong direction.

Most of the time, you can achieve this automatically, no need for specific selectors.

Margin, for instance:

Just set it both for left and right margin. The browser will choose the correct one for you

```css
#app {
    width: 300px;
    background: tomato;
    margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" dir="ltr">
  <h1>
    margin left 15
  </h1>
</div><div id="app" dir="rtl">
  <h1>
    margin right 5
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution is the most clean one, and I already try to apply it in most of the cases. But my issue is for the elements that specifically need to have a margin left or right.

Comment: I believe that this is what I am try to show. I have edited the snippet to make it more clear, with 2 different margins for left and right

Comment: I think that my question or my example isn't clear enough. For instance, I want the title to have a margin of 5px before the text, so I have to add a `margin-left` if the direction is `ltr` or `margin-right` in 'rtl`.