# How to align a HTML element to start or end position instead left or right

Tags: html, css, alignment, right-to-left

How to align a HTML element to start or end position instead left or right like Android XML. I want to position an element on right side when LTR (left to right) direction and set position on left side when RTL direction.

I tried

```
.element{float:end;}
.element{position: absolute; end: 10px;}
```

Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: instead of `end:`, did you tried `left:0` or `right:0` with position absolute? Also, you can take a look at `display:flex` and `align-self: flex-end`. `float` value can be or `left` or `right`, there's no `end`

Comment: @CalvinNunes i tried right: with position absolute, but it align always right side both LTR and RTL

Comment: please clearly explain what u r trying to do, add expected output image it will be helpful

Comment: The [`:dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir) pseudo class currently has poor browser support; but if you have the text direction specified on the element or some ancestor using the HTML `dir` attribute, you could use that with an attribute selector. So you could specify `right` instead of `left` then, and overwrite `left` with `auto`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you want, but I think you'll need a CSS precompiler or some JS functions. Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52516820/8732818, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48424311/8732818 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/40779933/8732818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-direction: row /*default*/
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container" dir="ltr">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="flex-container" dir="rtl">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Use `flex-direction` with value `row` for left-to-right, and `row-reverse` for right-to-left.

Use `justify-content` to align items in the main axis (`flex-direction` with value of `row` or `row-reverse` - main axis: x, `column` or `column-reverse` - main axis: y). Where `flex-end` or `flex-start` will mean the end or beginning of the axis's direction - using `flex-end` will align to the right if you use `flex-direction: row` (ltr), and it will align to the left if you use `flex-direction: row-reverse` (rtl).

**Update**

The above is all true, but if you specify `dir` on an element, the flex container will automatically detect the direction. (if you set `dir="rtl"`, it will behave as `flex-direction: row-reverse` without actually setting it)

Knowing this, you can check:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  if (navigator.language/*=== rtlLanguage*/) {
    document.body.dir = "rtl";
  }
};
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-direction: row /*default*/
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this will solve 50% of my problem, is there any way to add ltr/rtl class names from user's browser settings?

Comment: As I see, if you put dir attribute on an element, a flexbox will automatically detect the direction. See my updated example.

Comment: Updated again, now with checking the browser's language. Hope it helps.